# php mysql delete statement

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I am displaying a list of values in a table, What I am trying to do is add a delete button based off of the tables unique table id.

So I am trying to delete a value from my database using a this button i have declared, however with what I am doing at the moment it's just not deleting anything to the database.

This is my database table

```
CREATE TABLE `5050goosedown` (
    `goosedown_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',  
    `width` int(8),
    `height` int(8),
    `normal_fill` int(8),
    `our_fill` int(8),
    `old_price` DECIMAL(3,2),
    `price` DECIMAL(3,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY  (`goosedown_id`)
    ) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

this is my button, its inside a form which reloads this same page..

```
echo '<td><input type="submit" name="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'" value="Delete" /></td>"';
```

So this is a button that says Delete, and its name is the unique id of that table...  (one of the several tabels I have and would like to do this on)

Then when the page reloads I have this if statement to capture the particular delete button being pressed... which is not working atm..

```
//DELETE QUERIES
if(isset($_POST['goosedown_id']) and is_numeric($_POST['goosedown_id']))
{
  // here comes your delete query: use $_POST['deleteItem'] as your id
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM 5050goosedown WHERE goosedown_id='goosedown_id'");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to:

```
echo '<td><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'" /><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Delete" /></form></td>"';
```

and script:

```
if(isset($_POST['goosedown_id']) and is_numeric($_POST['goosedown_id'])){
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM 5050goosedown WHERE goosedown_id=".(int)$_POST['goosedown_id']);
}
```

You do not pass the `ID` with sumbit button as it's value is `Delete`, you need to create an hidden field.

Comment: +1 `name="goosedown_id" value="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'"` now you've got it ;-)

Comment: :), I made a mistake when I cleaned the code and accidentally deleted that part.

Answer (score 1):

As `goosedown_id` is defined as  `int(11) unsigned` you must not quote it in your query:

```
"DELETE FROM 5050goosedown WHERE goosedown_id=$goosedown_id"
//                                            ^           ^ no quote
```

And of course $goosedown_id is the posted value from the form:

```
$goosedown_id = (int)$_POST['goosedown_id'];
//               ^^^ prevents SQL Injection
```

So you have to do a 'fake' post, because the value cannot be in the submit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="<?php echo $row['goosedown_id'] ?>" />
```

You can also write this as a complete php string:

```
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="' . $row['goosedown_id'] . '" /> ?>
```

Comment: cool thank you.. however i do get an error on this line **echo "<td><input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'" /></td>";** the error says **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in**

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM 5050goosedown WHERE goosedown_id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST'goosedown_id'));
```

Also, make sure that the button is in fact inside a `form` with `method="post"`.